# How to pass a number from a PHP file into an Android TextView?

Tags: php, android, json

I have a PHP file that counts the total amount of rows in a database and outputs 382.

```
include('connect.php');

$counter = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM records");
$num = mysql_fetch_array($counter);
$count = $num["id"];
echo("$count");
```

I want to pass that number 382 into a textview in my android activity.

Answer (score 1):

Return that value in JSON format using `json_encode($array)` and then download it by your Android application,  here you have a tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/

Example :

```
$returning = array("Object" => "Value", [...]);
echo json_encode($returning);
```

Comment: Why would I use $array if I'm not passing an array just one integer?

Comment: @JSON Because you must, I will give an example